# set speed of robot with moveit

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,guys,
in moveit it has api to set speed of the robot?

thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328061/set-speed-of-robot-with-moveit/) by [luca123](https://answers.ros.org/users/44023/luca123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/time_parameterization/time_parameterization_tutorial.html

---

Originally posted by [jclinton830](https://answers.ros.org/users/38971/jclinton830/) with karma: 91 on 2019-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luca123](https://answers.ros.org/users/44023/luca123/) on 2019-07-10**:
thank you very much

**Comment by [jclinton830](https://answers.ros.org/users/38971/jclinton830/) on 2019-07-10**:
no worries!